# Picturebox change location on mouseenter without white borders appearing

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I'm trying to do the effect that the button is pressed, so when mousenter moving 2px the picturebox, I'm using picturebox as button because It allows me to set transparent backgrounds.
I tried forcing the background to transparent in various events(paint,pevious change location,after change location),but without success.
I think that is caused for the re-drawing when changing an element, because the white part of the background that whas "hidden" by the picturebox appears.

Any idea how to solve that?

Thanks in advance

```
 private void buttonX2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ((PictureBox) sender).Location = new Point(
    ((PictureBox) sender).Location.X, ((PictureBox) sender).Location.Y - 2);

 }


 private void buttonX2_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ((PictureBox)sender).Location = new Point(
    ((PictureBox)sender).Location.X, ((PictureBox)sender).Location.Y + 2);

 }
```

[image: Nothing to see here]

[image: The Program View]

Comment: I don't think I can understand. So are buttonX2 and button3 PictureBoxes? Are they the same? A typo? Are they covered by something? By what? Do you realialze that Control __transparency__ is only __faked__ by painting the old background, from the point in time, when the _pseudo-transparent_ control was added to its parent?

Comment: There are multiple buttons,I updated the names to prevent confusion, and added a image of the form.
The idea is in the mousenter of any of the picturebox, the location change to y+2,and when mouseleave y-2,but witouth appear the white when redrawing.
I know that the transparency is faked, and that is the cause that appears the white border I think,becouse have to redraw the part of the image that was hide by the picturebox, but maybe is some way to prevent that visual issue.

Comment: OK, now what exactly is under these buttons? The form? And it's background image?? This shouldn't be affected by moving controls around!

Comment: Your UI is very dark, any unpainted parts of the window will be starkly visible.  A poorly designed BackgroundImage can make it a lot worse.  Set the Opacity property of the form to 99 for a band-aid.  Forcing the WS_EX_COMPOSITED style flag of the window on is another workaround.

Comment: Why on earth are you moving the picturebox? Draw two images *normal and enter*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come from moving in or out too slowly. If you do that you will say enter from below, but the PB is moving up so you're out of it again, so it moves down and therefore you're in it again etc..The correct repainting of the Background can't keep up with these 'Jittering ButtBoxes'..

First, as Hans noted, make things less obtrusive: make the Form's `BackColor` dark, maybe even black!

Second to avoid the problem of jittering, move the Mouse Cursor itself a few pixels with the Pictureboxes, like this:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox PB = (PictureBox)sender;
    Point MP = Cursor.Position;
    this.SuspendLayout();
    PB.Location = new Point( PB.Location.X, PB.Location.Y - 2);
    Cursor.Position = new Point(MP.X, MP.Y - 2);
    this.ResumeLayout();

}

private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox PB = (PictureBox)sender;
    Point MP = Cursor.Position; 
    this.SuspendLayout();
    PB.Location = new Point( PB.Location.X, PB.Location.Y + 2);
    Cursor.Position = new Point(MP.X, MP.Y + 2);
    this.ResumeLayout();
}
```

Comment: The part of setting black the form backround added to the change the cursor position make the trick.
Thanks